# Managing someone who can't work on more than 1 ticket a day?

Tags: manager, software-development

I have a really toxic developer who I tried to reach for 2 hours and he told me he didn't respond to me, because he was too focused on his task. Then I mentioned he had a blocker and when I asked him how many days he spent on it, he lied and said 3, then I told him he was working on it for 2 months and then just spewed a sarcastic comment, and said 12 months, and then when I counted the amount of days I counted 17 and it was because he kept switching tasks for some reason. Anyway, this guy is telling me he can't work on more than 1 task a day. I find it ridiculous. He had a blocker, and I think I can help him on that in a single day or less. He's having difficulty using the Google Drive API to upload file, and he's supposed to be an ex-lead developer. I had other similar incidents, so I am wondering what I need to do from now on. I don't think he's a very good developer. I think I can only give him 3 more months before he shows some improvements. I am his manager, but I do 5 times more tickets than him. The only issue is that whenever we hire someone, they tend to be really incompetent for some reason.

Comment: Unless you can add an actual question (which people can answer) this is probably going to get closed, to be honest

Comment: "The only issue is that whenever we hire someone, they tend to be really incompetent for some reason."

Apart from suggesting to complain to HR and demand to be part of the hiring process, I really don't see what you want us to help with...

Comment: Please edit your question so that it's more readable.  One long paragraph is difficult to read and follow.  It's also not necessary or helpful to write this as a "rant".  Be professional and you will get better answers.

Comment: Does your company offer training for managers in the coaching of employees?

Comment: Are ticket metrics really the right metric to evaluate the output and quality of an employee's work? Some of my tasks take weeks to complete. I may work on the same ticket for weeks.

Comment: The second sentence makes little sense to me. Why did you ask him how long he had spent on the task if you already knew? I don't understand the point of the interaction at all.

Comment: For some reason this quote springs to mind: "If you run into an asshole in the morning, you ran into an asshole. If you run into assholes all day, you're the asshole." Not saying that OP necessarily is, but they should at least consider why everyone else apart from them appears to be incompetent.

Answer (score 15):

Since you really didn't ask a question, I just want to adress the last sentence:

> The only issue is that whenever we hire someone, they tend to be really incompetent for some reason.

Either your hiring process sucks.
Or your managing process sucks, and your company turns good people into bad people.

Find out which one is it, and fix it!

Comment: This is the answer. Wonder if the OP will accept it ?